# Take a screenshot of a WPF window with the predefined image size without losing quality

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, screenshot

When I take a screenshot of a current WPF window, the image resolution is that of my monitor (if the app is maximized), which is ok. However, if I was to print that image to a much bigger format, the image would look blurry. I found the way to capture the current window, and save it as a png file, but it's not doing the trick. The image is saved with the resolution I set, but the actual wpf window takes only a small portion of the saved image. Example is taken from:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saveenr/archive/2008/09/18/wpf-xaml-saving-a-window-or-canvas-as-a-png-bitmap.aspx

```
        var screen = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsActive);

        var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(4000, 4000, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

        rtb.Render(screen);

        var enc = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.PngBitmapEncoder();
        enc.Frames.Add(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

        using (var stm = System.IO.File.Create("ScreenShot.png"))
        {
            enc.Save(stm);
            using (Image img = Image.FromStream(stm))
            {
                Rectangle dest = new Rectangle(0, 0, 6000, 4000);

                using (Graphics imgG = Graphics.FromImage(img))
                {
                    imgG.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                    imgG.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    imgG.DrawImage(img, dest);
                }

                img.Save("NewScreenShot.png");
            }
        }
```

So basically, I'd like to capture the screenshot with the resolution of 4000 x 4000, if that's possible, without losing quality. 
The above code produces an image of 4000 x 4000, however the screenshot only takes a small portion of it, its original resolution.

Comment: So you have a small window, say 400x400 and you want to scale it to 4000x4000?

Comment: if it's possible. To scale it a bit higher, and save the image of the WPF window with a bit more resolution

Comment: Can you add your images to the post?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To scale your image, you can use a `DrawingVisual` and a `ScaleTransform` :

```
var w = 4000;
var h = 4000;

var screen = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsActive);

var visual = new DrawingVisual();
using (var context = visual.RenderOpen())
{
    context.DrawRectangle(new VisualBrush(screen),
                          null,
                          new Rect(new Point(), new Size(screen.Width, screen.Height)));
}

 visual.Transform = new ScaleTransform(w / screen.ActualWidth, h / screen.ActualHeight);

 var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(w, h, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
 rtb.Render(visual);

 var enc = new PngBitmapEncoder();
 enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

 using (var stm = File.Create("ScreenShot.png"))
 {
     enc.Save(stm);
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but, unfortunately this produces the exact same result as my code does, an image of 4000x4000 but the screenshot is of the same size and only takes a small portion of the newly generated image

Comment: @Mefhisto1 I wrote "screen" instead of "visual". Can you try this? (if it didnt work after the correction, can you share a demo test of your project and your pictures?)